# Multi-value parameter array works fine only when the text field to enter the parameter is blank

Tags: sql, arrays, string, drop-down-menu, reporting-services

I am trying to create a report in ReportViewer that uses a multi-value parameter.  I am passing this multi-value parameter into the stored procedure as an array of strings.  When the field for entering this parameter manually is blank, it works just fine with multiple parameters.

However, I want this field to be populated with a drop-down menu in ReportViewer that allows users to click on the specific parameters they like.  To enable this field to be populated with a drop-down menu, I right-clicked on the parameter name in ReportBuilder, selected Parameter Properties, clicked on the Available Values option, and selected the "Get values from a query" option.  This drop-down menu allows users to click on checkboxes for the values they wish to filter the report by, instead of typing them in.  When I select multiple checkboxes in this parameter field manually, it works just fine.  However, when I attempt to pass in the parameters for this field automatically from an external program, it doesn't work right.  If I pass a single value into this parameter automatically, no problem.  But if I attempt to pass multiple values into this parameter automatically, it's like I never entered any parameters into this field.

This makes absolutely no sense to me whatsoever.  I have tried editing the report using ReportBuilder by right-clicking on the Dataset, selecting DataSet Properties, clicking on Parameters, and using this expression for the value of the parameter:

**=Join(Parameters!IndustryNums.Value, ",")**

That has not solved the problem.  I have tried passing the parameter values into the stored procedure as an array of strings rather than a comma-delimited string, and that has not solved the problem.  I have been searching for answers on this site and other sites for days.  I don't know what else to do.  Any assistance anyone can provide me would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to resolve this problem.  The parameters that I was passing into the report automatically were integer values.  So I went into Microsoft SQL Server Report Builder, right-clicked on the IndustryNums parameter, selected Parameter Properties, and changed the Data Type from Text to Integer.

The bottom line-Make sure the data type for your parameter in Report Builder matches the data type for your parameter in your application code.